# Three js object z position moving on bowl

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Im making a threejs game.

Now, what should happen is, a ball that comes from z-position -5000 to 0.

This is how i create the mesh:

```
    let geometry  = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32);
    let material  = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: loader.load("images/SoftballColor.jpg"), side: THREE.BackSide
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh.position.set(0,0, -5000);
```

In the render, I run this code (ball coming closer):

```
mesh.position.z += 50;
```

the ball comes to me, but in a straight line

What i would like to do, is do this in a bowl. Any ideas?

I'll add some images to make it more clear.

Thank you in advance.

Ball movement:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sinus` function will help.

```
var how_high = 1000;
var start_position = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-5000);
```

You know the z-value of ball's position, so, its y-value will be

```
ball.position.y = Math.sin(ball.position.z / start_position.z * Math.PI) * how_high;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/u44u38pc/) example

Comment: Thank you! Works great now :)